# Can't seem to get this counter working

Tags: javascript

Hi Im trying to build a simple web browser game where it will time you on how fast you can click a keyboard key up to a limit (e.g 50, 75, 100). I have this code here:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="dt"></p>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var count = 0;
var IsGameAlive = 1;
window.onload = function() {
  myFunction()
}
document.onkeydown = function(e){
  if (IsGameAlive==1) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
      if(key==32){
          add();
      }
  }
}
function myFunction() {
  setInterval (stopwatch,1)
}
function stopwatch() {
  document.getElementById('dt').innerHTML = count;
}
function add() {
  count = count + 1;
}
if (count==50) {
  gamefinished();
}
function gamefinished() {
  window.alert("You Won!");
  IsGameAlive = 0;
  console.log("test");
}
```

I cant seem to get the if statement to execute the function that will disable the controls and to display an alert. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a JSFiddle?

Comment: Grabbing an element from the DOM every millisecond probably isn't a good idea fwiw.

Comment: You if statement will be called once, most likely before your dom is even ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement should be inside your function. So, instead of:

```
function add() {
  count = count + 1;
}
if (count==50) {
  gamefinished();
}
```

Should be:

```
function add() {
  count = count + 1;
  if (count==50) {
    gamefinished();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works, can you give me a short explanation of why it didn't work? I've only started Javascript. Thanks :)

Comment: The way you had it before, the if statement was not inside any of the functions. Any code not inside a function will only execute once, when the page initially loads. You want it to execute *every* time the count changes, so you need to put it inside the add() function. Hope that helps!

Comment: If this was helpful, please consider accepting and upvoting - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want, is the 'if' inside your keydown function, otherwise it will run once, at time of js execution.

```
window.onload = function() {
    myFunction()
    document.onkeydown = function(e){
      if (IsGameAlive==1) {
          e = e || window.event;
          var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
          if(key==32){
              add();
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Also, as Andy mentioned in comments, you may want to change your timer to 1 second instead of 1 / 1000 of a second

```
function myFunction() {
  setInterval (stopwatch,1000)
}
```

Comment: I edited it in, still not working, anymore suggestions?

Comment: throw throwing that `document.onkeydown` section inside your `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

Judging from you current code, it would seem there are a few simple general errors, so heres a cleaned up version:

```
var count = 0;
var IsGameAlive = true; //use booleans
var interval; //store interval
window.onload = function() {
    myFunction(); //missing semi-colons
    if (IsGameAlive) { //if statement should be contained inside window.onload
      document.onkeydown = function(e){
          if (IsGameAlive){ //prevent detection when game ended
               e = e || window.event;
              var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
              if(key==32){
                  add();
              }
          }
      }
    }
}; //missing semi-colons

function myFunction() {
    interval = setInterval(stopwatch,1000); //missing semi-colons, and run every 1000 = 1 second
}
function stopwatch() {
    document.getElementById('dt').innerHTML = count;
}
function add() {
    count = count + 1;
    if (count>=50) {
        gamefinished();
    }
    return;
}
function gamefinished() {
    window.alert("You Won!");
    IsGameAlive = false;
    clearInterval(interval); //remove interval
    return;
}
```

**Edit**
For better time keeping, perhaps set the timer back to running say every 10 milliseconds, but then using a function such as the one below to get a more accurate time. (this is also less resource intensive, whilst remaining very accurate, compared to using a timer set at 1 milliseconds).

```
var initialTime = Date.now(); //global variable

function getSecondsPassed(){
    return Math.floor((Date.now()-initialTime)/1000);
}
```